# GWT equivalent of jQuery change() for form elements

Tags: java, jquery, gwt

Can anyone tell me whether there is an equivalent method in GWT like `change` in jQuery for form elements like radio-buttons, checkboxes, etc, which is fired the moment any such button is checked or unchecked? If so, how do I use it? I found a method like `addValueChangeHandler` in the Google docs, but apart from providing the prototype, there is no working example.

Specifically, if I want a handler which will wait for a checkbox being checked or unchecked, and accordingly pop up an alert like **A checkbox has been checked!**!, along with that buttons accompanying text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CheckBox newOption = new CheckBox();
newOption.setText("Check to see alert");
newOption.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Boolean>() {

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Boolean> event) {
        if (event.getValue()) {
            Window.alert("Checkbox is checked!");
        } else {
            Window.alert("Checkbox is unchecked!");
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the `ValueChangeEvent<Boolean> event` thing? I cannot understand what it is supposed to mean...

Comment: When a checkbox is checked, it fires a ValueChangeEvent. This event should have a parameter - for CheckBox, it's `Boolean`, for TextBox it's `String`. This is how all events work in GWT, but other types of Events (i.e. ClickEvent, KeyUpEvent, etc.) do not need a parameter.